# Knockoutjs valueHasMutated Error in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

I'm not seeing where the error is here. I have similar code for another section of the same page with a similar setup that works fine in IE, but this throws an error. 
I initially tried to just push each of the values on but IE had issues (See http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html).

```
function DocSubType( doc_subtype_id, description ) {
    this.doc_subtype_id = ko.observable( doc_subtype_id );
    this.description = ko.observable( description );
};  
....
docsubtypeModel = [ ], //Where the loaded descriptions are stored. Knockout observers this.

viewDocSubTypeModel = {
    docsubtypes: ko.observableArray(docsubtypeModel),
....
download: function() {
    $.getJSON( DocSubTypesettings.list, function( json ) {
        //Push to the original model and then stated that it has mutated to speed up performance in IE.
        var tmparray = viewDocSubTypeModel.docsubtypes();
        for( i=0; i < json.docsubtypes.length; i++ ) {
            tmp = new DocSubType( json.docsubtypes[i].doc_subtype_id, json.docsubtypes[i].description );
            tmparray.push( tmp );
        }
        viewDocSubTypeModel.docsubtypes.valueHasMutated(); /*ERROR HERE*/        
    });
}
```

IE8 reports "JScript Object expected" knockout-1.2.1.js, line 34 character 262. (or knockout-1.2.1.debug.js, line 928 character 19)

Comment: The latest version of knockout is `knockout-2.1.0.js`. Why don't you upgrade it?

Comment: Just noticed that and did, same issue. The strange thing is that it works fine with 2 similar viewModel setups on the same page and breaks with 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had written a sort helper that was causing evaluate to fail.